# Как перед запуском одного .desktop файла сделать автоматический запуск другого .desktop файла?

Tags: linux, bash, fedora

Всем привет! У меня есть игра Risk of Rain 2, и она запускается только тогда когда запущен стим. Для запуска игры использую bottles, куда установил стим, а уже в стим добавил исполняемый файл игры. Bottles предусматривает создание ярлыков, и я создал ярлык игры и стима, но для полного счастья хотелось бы чтобы сразу по нажатию ярлыка игры запускался стим, просто в самом стиме функция добавления ярлыка игры на рабочий стол почему то не работает. Вот встал вопрос: можно ли в .desktop файл игры куда нибудь добавить комманду которая открывала бы .desktop файл игры (в моем случае gtk-launch Steam.desktop)?

На данный момент получилось только добавить в меню запуска приложения возможность запустить стим, но хочется чтобы автоматически все происходило. Вот содержимое .desktop файла:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Risk of Rain 2
Exec=bottles-cli run -p 'Risk of Rain 2' -b 'Steam'
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Categories=Application;
Icon=steam_icon_892970
Comment=Launch Risk of Rain 2 using Bottles.
Actions=Configure;Postscript;
[Desktop Action Configure]
Name=Изменить в Bottles
Exec=bottles-cli -b 'Steam'
[Desktop Action Postscript]
Name=Запустить Steam
Exec=gtk-launch Steam--Steam--1656704529.337303.desktop
```

Comment: можешь показать что у тебя прописано в .desktop risk'a?

Comment: Добавил к своему вопросу

Comment: соедините две команды в одну строку Exec=command1 && command2

Comment: Exec=bottles-cli run -p 'Risk of Rain 2' -b 'Steam' && bottles-cli run -p 'Steam' -b 'Steam-cli' вообще может что-нибудь такое следует попробовать